# EC2 instance having only 1 GB RAM instead of 8GB

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory

I recently took over a project which is hosted on AWS EC2.
There is a EC2 instance type m4.large which should have 8 GB of RAM.

The output of `free -m` only shows 1 GB

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           993        848        144         29        121        262
-/+ buffers/cache:        464        528
Swap:            0          0          0
```

The output of `top`does the same:

```
Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1017292k total,   869792k used,   147500k free,   124744k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   268672k cached
```

**How can I make the missing RAM useable?**

Comment: I would guess this would be a provisioning error on the instance so the simplest thing to do would be to take a snapshot and relaunch it as an m4.large. I would also suggest reaching out to AWS support who may be able to fix it but importantly should be able to reimburse you for incorrect provisioning.

Comment: Also, what is the OS running on the instance, particularly the kernel or AMI? There's an outside possibility that it may be something to do with that.

Comment: Its running Amazon Linux AMI with Kernel version 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64.

Comment: You confirmed that running `ec2metadata --instance-type` (on the instance itself) shows `m4.large`?

Comment: I get `ec2metadata: command not found` for both root and ec2-user

Comment: regarding the instance meta-data you can query the instance type using `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type` in a terminal inside the instace